# Why is there a "Loading..." delay for every razor page navigation in a Blazor Webassembly application?

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Webassembly PWA application with two razor pages: Index.razor and History.razor. Every time a user navigates between the two pages, there is a short delay where the "Loading..." HTML is displayed on the page before the app loads the actual razor page.

I understand that when you first open the app in your browser it needs to download all the necessary assemblies and load them. But once they've navigated to site, why does each navigation require that the "Loading..." html be shown? It's often a short period of time (I have my service worker caching everything), but as a user this would feel distracting to me.

I haven't been able to find anything online explaining this. I'm sure I'm probably missing how this actually works, or maybe I have setup my page/navigation incorrectly? Any information on this would be greatly appreciated. How does the page loading work with each navigation? Is there a way to prevent this?

UPDATE: Using the the Blazor WebAssembly template in Visual Studio as an example and following Mister Magoo's comment, I was able to figure out that the reason the "Loading..." shows up is because I am doing a full reload of the pages. That leads me to one last question. If the user is currently on the Index page, and they click to navigate to Index, is there a way to clear out all the Models on that page without forcing a refresh?

Comment: How are you navigating between pages - because the Loading... message usually only displays for a full page load

Comment: Are you loading data in the Page OnInitialization life-cycle if so make sure you do it async so the page will not lock up while the data is being fetched.

Comment: @MisterMagoo You're right, that was it. I was doing full page reloads. I was able to change my navigation to and from Index and History to not reload the page and that works. However, if I'm currently on the Index page, and I want the Models being used on that page to be re-initialized when I hit the Index navigation menu item, is there a way to do that without completely refreshing the page?

Comment: You'd need to make sure you are not hanging on to any references to the models, then each "page" should be disposed when you leave it

Comment: Just saw your updated question.. that's harder and I'm on mobile. If no-one else helps I'll get back to you later

Answer (score 0):

There are many strategies on caching in service worker you can set it depends on your needs

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies

I think "Cache First" strategy is proper for you